# Bootstrap v3: text boxes in well are overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to design a page header inside a bootstrap v3 'well' div. This header should contain a title (big text from the left), a last updated timestamp (lower left corner) and a small logon toolbar (lower right corner). This works mostly fine but now I'm trying to add a padded border around the last updated and logon toolbar divs, and it seems only the text itself stays inside the well, the padded borders are overflowing the bottom of the well.

See this bootply for an example: http://www.bootply.com/127078

Any idea's how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the overflow property to your css element .well-titlebar, that should fix it

```
.well-titlebar{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, nicer solution than Billy Moat (which also works fine btw), therefor I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you place another div around your two floated divs with the clearfix class on it that should sort it out.

```
<div class="well well-titlebar">
    <div class="PageTitleText">Page title!</div>
        <div class="clearfix">  
            <div class="PageTitleLastUpdated">Last Updated:February 25 2014.</div>
                <div class="PageTitleLogon">Logged on as: Alex Goris (<a href="http://localhost/Login.php?Action=Logout">Logout</a>):
    <a href="#"><span onclick="OpenUserInfoWindow('0008')">View Profile</span></a>| <a href="#"><span onclick="OpenUserEditWindow('0008')">Edit Profile</span></a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/127089